# Structural Patterns as objects in Python

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, pattern-matching, match

Would there be a way in python (standard lib, or 3rd party library) to extract a structural pattern as an object, similar to how you can do that for regex patterns? Basically I would like to pass a structural pattern as an argument to a function.

For example (tentative syntax):

```py
x = TypeVar('x')
pat = Pattern[[1, x, 3, 4]]
res = match(pat, [1,2,3,4])
res # {"x" : 2}
```